# Azure Media Service, How to published encoded video, using php sdk when I turn the streaming unit scale to 0 (zero)

Tags: php, azure

After I turn my streaming unit scale, from 1 to 0 (zero) on the Azure admin. All my published url wont published. Any help how can I do this on php sdk

Comment: Of course your published content will not work when you scale to 0 (zero) Streaming Units. A zero cannot stream your content.

Comment: We are using Azure media services to encode videos in different bitrate. Looking at the billing the amount is outrageous for Streaming units, so we turned the streaming units to 0. But some of the Microsoft guys said that there is no connection even you turned the streaming unit to 0.  Meaning you can still published the encoded video.

Comment: I am trying to change some of the parameters sets on the SDK like turning the const DYNAMIC_ENVELOPE_ENCRYPTION to NO_DYNAMIC_ENCRYPTION on createAssetDeliveryPolicy helper function and other thing. It still finished the whole process from uploading, create the asset until it published  the encoded asset with no errors. But when I see it on the Azure Media service admin, the status is still not published.

Comment: Well apparently it can run without streaming unit if you run the encoded mp4 file directly.

Answer (score 0):

As @astaykov said, the published content doesn't work with zero streaming unit.

For delivering content, please refer to the tutorial [Upload Files into a Media Services account using REST API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/media-services-rest-upload-files/) to do this in PHP with REST APIs.

Meanwhile, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php#media-services if you want to do this in Azure SDK for PHP.